# Font-related errors when printing as pdf in internet explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, printing, font-awesome, webfonts

I have a site that uses font-awesome icons. When attempting to print a page as pdf, Internet Explorer 11 produces an error:

```
%%[ ProductName: Distiller ]%%
Roboto-Regular not found, using Courier.
FontAwesome not found, using Courier.
%%[Page: 1]%%
%%[ Error: invalidfont; OffendingCommand: show; ErrorInfo: CharOffsets  %%[      Flushing: rest of job (to end-of-file) will be ignored ]%%
%%[ Warning: PostScript error. No PDF file produced. ] %%
```

Printing as PDF does not seem to be an issue in the other browsers I've tested. How can I work around this in internet explorer?

Answer (score 0):

Not a full solution, but a work around is to uncheck the "Rely on system fonts only; do not use documents fonts" in the Preferences section of the print dialog.

Answer (score 0):

It appears from the messages you posted that what you're printing is referencing both Roboto-Regular and FontAwesome fonts, but Adobe Distiller (attempting to Distill PostScript output to PDF) is unable to find them in its resource location(s) on the host machine. Its attempt to substitute Courier is not succeeding. (I'm not sure that a successful substitution of Courier would be useful anyway.)

Verify that you do have both those fonts available on the machine, and that Distiller is finding the resource folder where they've been placed. Update as needed, by either moving your font(s) into those locations or adding a new one. e.g. In Adobe Acrobat Distiller X, pressing Ctrl+L will bring up a popup listing of locations where Distiller will be looking for fonts.